# Mutual authentication Android and Tomcat

Tags: java, android, tomcat, ssl

i want to make a mutual auth for my app and server.
I follow this step:

1) Create a certf. and keystore for the server tomcat (tomcat.keystore)

2) Create a certf. for the client

3) Import client certf. into server keystore

4) Create a bks keystore for Android (smartssl.bks)

5) Import certf. server and client into keystore Android

Now i configure Tomcat with:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="true"
            keystoreFile="/home/antonio/Documenti/keystore/tomcat.keystore"
            keystorePass="pass" maxThreads="150" port="8443" scheme="https"
            secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
            truststoreFile="/home/antonio/Documenti/keystore/tomcat.keystore"
            truststorePass="pass" />
```

And in the Android app i use Volley framework like that:

```
 InputStream keyStore = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.smartssl);

                // Usually getting the request queue shall be in singleton like in {@see Act_SimpleRequest}
                // Current approach is used just for brevity
                RequestQueue queue = Volley
                        .newRequestQueue(Act_SsSslHttpClient.this,
                                         new ExtHttpClientStack(new SslHttpClient(keyStore, "pass", 443)));

                StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
                                                        "https://192.168.1.4:8443/REST/app/generali/getA",
                                                        createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                                                        createMyReqErrorListener()){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return createBasicAuthHeader("user", "strongpassword");
                }};

                queue.add(myReq);
            }
        });
```

With this config. i have this error:

```
no peer certificate
```

If i try to change Tomcat configuration with this:

```
clientAuth="false"
```

works, so the problem is in the bks file? or where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve with put in the app the Keystore and the Truststore in BKS.

Here there is a guide to create a self certificate:

[Create a self certificate for client and server](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/)

And here there is the class example for mutual auth with Volley:

[Example class for Mutual auth TLS/SSL](https://github.com/balduzzi85/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/Act_AuthSsSslHttpClient.java)

[Class SSLSocket](https://github.com/balduzzi85/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/toolbox/SslSocketFactory.java)

Comment: Hi @antonio, I tried above tutorial but not able to succeed. COuld you please provide me sample android project. My android app throws following exception: `java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Problem reading keystore stream`

Comment: @IB's maybe your keystore is BKS2.. try to crete the keystore with keyexplorer and select bks