# Mutual autentification using Tomcat and Android

Tags: java, android, tomcat, https

I'm trying make mutual autentification using Tomcat and Android. I did everything as stated on [Created self signed certificates](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/)

How I install this certificates in Tomcat and Android application and test between connection?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is creating the self signed certificates which you did following [creating self signed certificates](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/).

Next the certificates need to be [set up in Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

The interaction between Tomcat and Android [has been answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294282/mutual-authentication-android-and-tomcat)